# chat_member and my_chat_member dont work on this code in node-telegram-bot-api

Tags: telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

```
bot.on('chat_member', async msg => {
console.log(msg,'dsadsa')})
```

hi
this event dont work in this lib
[**node-telegram-bot-api**](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api)

but i dont know why?
i seen there is no `chat_member` in codes

```
`on(event: TelegramBot.MessageType | 'message', listener: (message: TelegramBot.Message, metadata: TelegramBot.Metadata) => void): this;

on(event: 'callback_query', listener: (query: TelegramBot.CallbackQuery) => void): this;

on(event: 'inline_query', listener: (query: TelegramBot.InlineQuery) => void): this;

on(event: 'poll_answer', listener: (answer: TelegramBot.PollAnswer) => void): this;

on(event: 'chosen_inline_result', listener: (result: TelegramBot.ChosenInlineResult) => void): this;

on(
    event: 'channel_post' | 'edited_message' | 'edited_message_text' | 'edited_message_caption' | 'edited_channel_post' | 'edited_channel_post_text' | 'edited_channel_post_caption',
    listener: (message: TelegramBot.Message) => void
): this;

on(event: 'shipping_query', listener: (query: TelegramBot.ShippingQuery) => void): this;

on(event: 'pre_checkout_query', listener: (query: TelegramBot.PreCheckoutQuery) => void): this;

on(event: 'polling_error' | 'webhook_error' | 'error', listener: (error: Error) => void): this;
```

`